# Using google auth along with jwt tokens (react)

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, google-oauth

I'm building a react+.net app and want to add google oauth. I already have normal login/register where I get a jwt token from backend but I struggle to understand how to integrate oauth with that (so I still get the jwt). Do I need a new endpoint? From what I read it seemed like I get an access token, send it to backend and then I do something so I get the jwt (and add user to my database if he is not there)? Pretty new to webdev and really struggling with it despite lots of googling, most videos show how to do it in react alone.